# What exactly I have to escape in simple grep pattern?

Tags: regex, grep

```
grep -E "c.+ features" test.txt
```

The above works great and is matching `call features`, etc. However, it is extended pattern.
How do I modify it to a simple pattern and know in general what exactly to escape?

I tried to escape `\+` without success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Escaping `+` as `\+` should work:

```
$ echo 'call features' | grep -E "c.+ features" 
call features
$ echo 'call features' | grep  "c.+ features" 
$ echo 'call features' | grep  "c.\+ features" 
call features
```

From the man pages:

> Basic vs Extended Regular Expressions
>          In basic regular expressions the meta-characters ?, +, {, |, (, and ) lose their special meaning; instead use the backslashed versions
>   \?, +,  {,
>          \|, (, and ).

Comment: Note that in certain cases you'll have to escape the backslash character too, e.g. `echo 'call features' | grep c.\\+\ features`